# Access array in PHP

Tags: php

How do I access the following array in PHP:

```
$Record =  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1);
```

I have tried

```
echo $Record[0];
```

But no luck :(

Comment: @ircmaxwell: With the exception of the `[]` in the declaration...

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 $Record =  array( 0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 1);
```

or even

```
 $Record = array(1,1,1);
```

and then

```
 echo $Record[0];
```

Keep in mind that print_r shows you some form of representation of the array. so this code:

```
$record1 = array(1,1,1);
print_r($record1);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: But I'm getting Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 from server which I need to parse. Tell me how can i do that?

Comment: How do you get that array? How do you "see" that you're getting this?

Comment: well, that's just the way it is represented, your array should be a normal array. let me add something to the answer

Comment: If I try to access it through $record[0] I get only 'A' which is the first character from "Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1)"

Comment: post the complete (relevant) data then

Answer (score 6):

To initialize an array (you don't need an associative array, if your keys are just the actual indices) use:

```
$record = array(1, 1, 1);
```

Then you can access the first element via:

```
$first = $record[0];
```

Comment: But I'm getting Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 from server which I need to parse. Tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Ok, thats a different situation. Try to post as much relevant information as possible in your question **question**. Maybe your questions was: *I have a string representation of an array in PHP, like ... How do I convert it to an actual array?* - or something along this line.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the above array. Is there any way to access its elements?

Answer (score 4):

`$Record =  Array ( 1, 1, 1 );`

your array has wrong syntax

Comment: But I'm getting Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 from server which I need to parse. Tell me how can i do that?

Comment: instead print_r () use serialize () or JSON_encode () or remove [] form the output

Comment: I have tried both but still no luck. Is there any formal way to try the above functions?

Comment: how you generate and capture your output ? provide actual code

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but you can try something like that:

```
$pattern = "|\[(\d+)\] => (\d+)|";
preg_replace_callback(
            $pattern,
            "add_to_array",
            $text);
```

and write a function 'add_to_array' to add to your array, get the index by $matches[1] and the value by $matches[2]!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your idea further in details.Thanks.